# Get Js FormData() In Web Api

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api

Is there a trick to getting formdata from a post request in web api?  I can't seem to be able to use namevaluecollection or formdatacollection when submitting a form on the frontend using js FormData().  I have checked the http request to verify the form data is being passed to the server.

JS Form Submit

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Email', 'email@notarealemail.com');
    formData.append('Password', '123');
    // submit data using xmlhttprequest
```

Controller Web Api

```
public IHttpActionResult CheckUser(FormDataCollection FormData)
{
     //formdatacollection and namevaluecollection don't seem to return key based values
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, in web api controllers you should check the property `Request` to get all information you post from your page. Next you can get your data by using appropriate method: `Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync` or `Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync` (it's probably your case) or `Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync`, etc. It depends on the sent data format.

Or you can always create a class with the respective fields and send it in JSON to get it another way:

```
public IHttpActionResult CheckUser(AccountData data)
{

}
```

And your class should look like:

```
public class AccountData {    
   public String Email { get; set; }    
   public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input